# How to remove Billing address from Magento?

Tags: magento, billing

I have to keep only Shipping address throughout Magento site.

I have found to not display billing address in checkout page, But i have to remove Billing Address from admin panel, emails from every where.

Please suggest anyone for this.

I have to totally remove Billing address.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, you want to delete all billing addresses? You could create and observer to hook onto the point where you want to delete all addresses of type 'billing'

Comment: @input No. I want only one address to new customers also. I mean person only be asked for only single address that is shipping address. not 2 different addresses. only one.

Comment: The following extension might help you.  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/express-checkout-2845.html